# How to click on captured image using sikuli

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, sikuli

[image]I am new to Sikuli. I am Automating a web application that have option to upload a file.
When I click on upload button it opens a popup window.In that window I have to select a file. How I can do it using sikuli.
I am using linux operating system so I can't use AutoIT.

Below is my code which I am trying

```
 public static void imageClick()
     {
         Screen s= new Screen();
         try {

            s.capture();

            s.find("Desktop.png");
             s.click("Desktop.png",0);
             System.out.println("Desktop is selected");
        } catch (FindFailed e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
```

Desktop.png is a image file which I kept in my project. first I am searching it then clicking on it.

Anyone can help me how I can achieve this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can capture the exact screenshot of text box that presents inside upload File dialog. And then use `s.type()` method to send filepath. Something like this: `s.type(new Pattern("./img/FileTextBox.png"),"/path/to/file/to/upload");`

Comment: @mk08: Actually in my case that text box is not coming.

Comment: Oh, can u share a screenshot of that dialog window? May be some workaround can be thought of.

Comment: @mk08: Please check dialogue which I get when I click on upload button

Comment: Well, you can first click on search, which will give the text box to send in the file to be searched. You can pass here the path of file & hit enter key programmatically. Now hit tab key to highlight the search result & click on Open button at the bottom.

Comment: Please note, this is a workaround. There might be a *to the point* solution which even I am missing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I done in in below way
First import sikuli jar file to your project
Capture the Image where you want to click and save it to some location
for Ex. /home/dev/Desktop/abc.png

Screen s = new Screen();            //Created the Object of screen class 
 s.click("/home/dev/Desktop/abc.png");

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void imageClick()
{
    Screen s= new Screen();
    Pattern DesktpIcon = new Pattern("Desktop.png");
    s.click(DesktpIcon);
    System.out.println("Desktop is Clicked.");
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it